# .desktop file. There was an error launching the application

Tags: unity, shortcuts

I am a new Ubuntu 12.04 user.

I've read my stuff and copied/pasted code from here and there trying to make my Second Life client have a shortcut on the sidebar. I did this before... I did a format to my hard drive and everything is lost. Here are the details:

Filename= **PhoenixViewer.desktop**

code inside the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application 
Name=PhoenixViewer 
Exec=/opt/PhoenixViewer/snowglobe
Comment=PhoenixViewer 
Categories=Games;
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/PhoenixViewer/phoenix_icon.png
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=snowglobe-do-not-run-directly
```

My dash can't even see the file as a desktop element. It lists it as PhoenixViewer.desktop and it has another icon than the one I list in code.
The paths are correct.

When I run it from nautilus in `/usr/share/applications/` I get the error:
There was an error launching the application.

And same goes if I copy paste the .desktop file on my desktop and run it.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What happens when your run `/opt/PhoenixViewer/snowglobe` through a terminal? What if you mark the .desktop file as executable (Properties->Permissions->Allow executing file as program) and then try to launch it?

Comment: Okay, I'm not that new. I did both before I post the question. Same thing. I even checked the other .desktop files, they don't have permission to execute. snowglobe IS executable (just in case). The problem is that for some reason my dash doesn't recognize my file as Desktop Entry. I even tried to re-create the file, just in case. Still nothing.

Comment: Ήντα γίνεται ρε παιδί;

Comment: Μια χαρά, τα Ubuntu μου τα σπάνε ολίγων τι... αλλά ντάξει.

Comment: @hakermania and DeusDeceit: Please keep your comments in English. (αν και με κάνατε να γελάσω, τρομάρα σας).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Phoenix Viewer
Comment=Second Life Client
Exec=/opt/PhoenixViewer/snowglobe
Icon=/opt/PhoenixViewer/phoenix_icon.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true 
StartupWMClass=snowglobe-do-not-run-directly
Categories=Game
```