# What would I write as a directory?

Tags: launcher, games, directory

I'm trying to write a .desktop link for Cave Story, a game that I'm trying to play. Someone put the code to make a launcher icon on the desktop and the code is:

```
sh -c "cd /your_cave_story_directory_here(linuxDoukutsu-1.01) && ./doukutsu"
```

The emplacement of the folder (I downloaded it as a .zip, don't know if it has to be one of not) is **Home** (I believe that it's $Home), **Linux Games**, and then **Cave Story** .

I'm sorry to ask this easy question but I'm really new to Ubuntu and I have no idea what to write as the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is what you want:

```
sh -c "cd /home/your_user_name/Linux\ Games/Cave\ Story && ./doukutsu"
```

or just only:

```
/home/your_user_name/Linux\ Games/Cave\ Story/doukutsu
```

where `your_user_name` is the name you have as a user in the system.

The `your_cave_story_directory_here` is actually meaning the folder where the **unzipped** game is.

Additionally you may want to read [How to add programs to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/224004/12218)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong but when I change the user for mine and save as "Cave Story.desktop", I change the file to allow it to be executable as a program and when I click on it it says ***"There was an error launching the application."*** Maybe the application is the problem? Maybe the code you gave me is right?

Comment: You may want to see this [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/203954/12218) and its accepted answer which seems the OP had similar problems. Check the differences in .dekstop files.